# Why am I getting undefined even using bind?

Tags: javascript, typescript, reflection, bind

```
interface LooseObject {
    [key: string]: any
}

class C
{
    protected x: number = 100
    protected y : number = 200
    public s: string = "my dear string"

    constructor()
    {
        this.x = 20
        this.y = 10
        this.s = "hello, world!"
    }

    public function sayHello(): void
    {
        console.log('message --> ', this.s)
    }

    public get a(): string { return this.s }
    public get n(): number { return this.x }
}

function classToRegularObject(obj: LooseObject)
{
    console.log('s = ', obj["s"])

    let p:LooseObject = {};
    for (; obj != null; obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))
    {
        for(var [k, v] of Object.entries(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)))
        {
            if(typeof v.get === 'function' && k !== '__proto__')
            {
                console.log('key = ', k, ', value = ', v.get.bind(obj)(), 
                            'val2 = ', obj[k])
                p[k] = obj[k]
            }
        }
    }
    
    return p
}
```

then

```
let k = new C();
console.log(k.s)
k.sayHello()
console.log(classToRegularObject(k))
```

but I'm getting `undefined` from this line `const vv = v.get.bind(obj);` what I missing?

Comment: Are you sure? When I paste your code here https://tsplay.dev/WzoL1w and click "run" I get `30`, `"baa"` and `20` as the `value =` in your log output. No `undefined` at all. If your still having trouble, then you'll need to explain what your code is doing and what you expect it to do, because trying to decipher 40 lines is single letter variable names that do _something_ with prototypes is not an easy task.

Comment: @AlexWayne yes, it doesn't work for me, locally. I don't know why yet... the purpose of the `f` function is convert the give class to a plain javascript object

Comment: @AlexWayne  check out the update

Comment: If I uncomment `p[k] = vv()` I get your expected output https://tsplay.dev/mx567W. I can even copy and paste the compiled JS output into the browser console, and I get the same output. Your code seems to work exactly as you expect it to. If it's giving you a different result then it's due to something you've not posted yet. I would recommend stepping through your example with a debugger until you discover what's going on here.

Comment: @AlexWayne I edited the code in the question to reproduce the error I'm getting.
From what I noticied, it happens when the get property return a field (this was what the initial code I posted missed)

Comment: @AlexWayne managed to make it work by typing the key string to index the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone needing same thing, managed to make it work with `keyof` operator:

```
            const keyTyped = k as keyof LooseObject
            const value = obj[keyTyped]
```

then I can do:

```
            p[k] = obj[keyTyped]
```

Get the value perfectly.